# How to validate and insert text into Excel sheet defined position based on input text value format?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I would like to parse inserted cell text and use it to properly fill cell data in the corresponding sheet. For instance, based on the value in cell `B2` on sheet `1.1` I would like to insert text, into specified location on the sheet `1.2`. The cell text specifies the destination location of data in the following format:

`<destination_sheet_name>:<destination_panel_id>:<destination_module_id>`

[image]

In that case the corresponding data on sheet `1.2` should look like below and contain location of data from the source sheet:
`<source_sheet_name>:<source_panel_id>:<source_module_id>`

[image]

Do you think is it possible without writing a VBA script? Can you propose an approach on how to achieve this for a non-pro Excel user ;-)?

Comment: Is it achievable: yes. Without VBA.. possibly but would be very cumbersome (that could just be my lack of knowledge though). Question: if you don't want a VBA based approach, why did you add the VBA tag? Also, for us to help you, you must atleast make an attempt to resolve your scenario

Comment: It is not possible without VBA. If you want formula approach, you should know that your source and target cells will not change. In this case, the "target" sheet can receive references from all the other sheets, while the "source" sheet can also be any other. So, if you write a formula in one sheet, that should stay fixed - but in your case, it seems you would overwrite it, therefore ruin all the logic.

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
2. Double click on the Workbook module in the left pane (usually called "ThisWorkbook").
3. Paste this code. I tried to comment essential parts.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim s() As String
  Dim shTarg As Worksheet
  Dim lngTargPanelRow As Long
  Dim lngTargModuleCol As Long
  Dim sSourcePanel As String
  Dim sSourceModule As String
  Dim c As Range

  On Error GoTo EndSub
  If Target.Count = 1 Then
    ' Checking if the new value in the cell  (ambiguously called Target) has 2 colons
    If Len(Target) - Len(Replace(Target, ":", "")) = 2 Then
      ' Making an array with elements which are separated by colons in the cell
      s() = Split(Target, ":")
      ' Associating the VBA object with the particular sheet by its name
      Set shTarg = Me.Sheets(s(0))
      ' Finding the target row
      Set c = shTarg.Range("$A:$A").Find(s(1))
      If c Is Nothing Then GoTo EndSub Else lngTargPanelRow = c.Row
      ' Finding the target column
      Set c = shTarg.Range("1:1").Find(Replace(s(2), "M", "Module "))
      If c Is Nothing Then GoTo EndSub Else lngTargModuleCol = c.Column
      ' Finding the source panel
      sSourcePanel = Sh.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
      ' Finding the source module
      sSourceModule = Sh.Cells(1, Target.Column).Value
      ' Shortening the source module name
      sSourceModule = Replace(sSourceModule, "Module ", "M")
      ' Putting the value into the target cell
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      shTarg.Cells(lngTargPanelRow, lngTargModuleCol) = Sh.Name & ":" & sSourcePanel & ":" & sSourceModule

    Else
EndSub:
      MsgBox "No changes were made in any other cell"
    End If

    If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox "Error " & Err & " - " & Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```